# Getting the text of all the Selected Checkbox in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm doing a project that requires a lot of checkboxes. And all those selected checkboxes will go to the texture or something trigger by a button. I already browse here and I came up with this.

[image: pnchk is the panel where the checkbox is placed.]

The code actually is almost what I'm looking for. But the problem is the way it displays.

[image: Display]

What I want is to remove those `[ , ]` because I want to be the one who controls the way the text is display.

Answer (score 0):

Well, passing the `checkboxes` List to the `showMessageDialog` method is implicitly calling `List#toString()`. The implementation of this method in class `ArrayList` is to print a comma-separated list of the values, just as you see it. If you want to display it in another way, you'd have to iterate over the elements of your list and build a string according to your likings.